# Can a wasp ingest and use a snake's venom?

Tags: zoology, entomology, toxicology, snakes

Some people claim that if one comes across a *dead venomous snake* one should always cut of and *bury the head* as otherwise wasps could reach the venom and add it to their own stinger, for example [this Answers.com answer](http://www.answers.com/Q/Why_do_you_bury_snake_heads):

> You bury a venomous snake's head because other animals or insects like wasps, bees and mosquitoes that are attracted to liquid like substances such as water are drawn to the venom. Wasps in particular will use mud and the **venom to build their nests**. The venom will remain in the wasp's system, causing them to be poisonous and **deadly if they sting you**.

Now to me this seems very strange as most animals that consume something break down all the proteins, neutralize any acids and dilute anything left over, but people who make those claims insist that this was similar to putting a white flower in a vase with blue dye turning blue as well.

Is this is a myth?

Comment: I'm looking for a more notable source than an Answers.com question that got only 7 upvotes, and a [Reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/v31ay/someone_just_told_me_always_bury_snakeheads/) that only got 3 upvotes. Has anyone else heard of this claim?

Comment: This seems highly implausible on a number of levels, and there doesn't appear to be any notable claim to this effect.

Comment: Insects eating poisonous plants and becoming poisonous themselves is well-known (e.g. [African variegated grasshopper/cinnabar moth](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/02/120221090240.htm)), even higher order animals like the [Blue poison dart frog](http://news.mongabay.com/2005/0809-frogs.html) derive their toxins from ants. 
But wasps specifically feeding on snake poison glands? I would suggest looking at the types of venom used by [wasps, bees and ants](http://www.compoundchem.com/2014/08/28/insectvenoms/) and the types used by [snakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_venom).